# Django Rest fields grouping and customising

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-rest-framework

I have a Django models like so:

```
class Floor(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_lenght =100)

class Point(models.Model):
    created_at      = fields.UnixDateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at      = fields.UnixDateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    floor           = models.ForeignKey(Floor)
    device          = models.CharField(max_lenght=100)
```

*creates_at* and *updated_at* are just custom fields with timestamps.

So, i need to send request like **points/?start=x,end=y,timeslice=z**, where x -
 is start timestamp, y - end timestamp, z - timeslice in this period. For example, if x is start of the day, and y is and of the day, and z is 3600? i will have 24 slices and want to have JSON like so:

```
{
    floor_id: floor_id
    slice: first timestamp of first slice 
    count: count of devices in this slice
},
{
    floor_id: floor_id
    slice: first timestamp of second slice 
    count: count of devices in this slice
}, 
...
```

Propably, i need to customise my serializers, using django-filters and write spetial view for this purpose, but i have no ideas how to put it together

UPD: Ok, i customise my serializer for Floor model, and now it looks like:

```
class FloorWithTPCountSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Floor
        fields = ('id', 'count')

    count = serializers.SerializerMethodField('get_tp_count')

    def get_tp_count(self, obj):
        return obj.trackpoint_set.values('tag').distinct().count()
```

And no i recive JSON like:

```
{
    "id": 28,
    "count": 3
},
{
    "id": 35,
    "count": 1
},
```

I can suggest, that i need to get querystring params in this serialize class and declarate a method for counting points within timeslice. So, how can i get querydict in serializer class?

Comment: your question is not so clear. what does the request **points/?start=x,end=y,timeslice=z** do? what are start, end and timeslice?

Comment: ohh, i'm so sorry, i corrected it.

Comment: just to be sure, you want to fetch list of all points that are created between start and end and are grouped together in some timeslices where a timeslice is a time period in seconds?

Comment: No, i wand to fetch count of points between start and end in each timeslice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, as i suggested early the key was in the serializer customisation. I have to declarete custom method for needed JSON structure.
Here is my solution:

```
class FloorWithTPCountSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Floor
        fields = ('id', 'results')

    results = serializers.SerializerMethodField('get_tp_start')

    def get_tp_start(self, obj):
        query_params = self.context.get("request").query_params
        aggregations = {'hour':3600, 'day':86400, 'week':604800}
        if 'start' in query_params and 'end' in query_params:
            st_tm = int(query_params.get('start'))
            en_tm = int(query_params.get('end'))
            if 'aggregation' in query_params:
                aggregation_value = query_params.get('aggregation')
                aggregation = aggregations.get(aggregation_value)
            else:
                aggregation = en_tm - st_tm
            trackpoint_set = obj.trackpoint_set
            st = [{'count': trackpoint_set.filter(created_at__gte=ts, created_at__lt=ts + aggregation).values(
                'tag').distinct().count(), 'timestamp': ts} for ts in range(st_tm, en_tm, aggregation)]

        else:
            st = None
        return st
```

Ofcourse, it still lacks some checks by querstring consistency, but i can fetch JSON form, as i needed.
For example, requesting

**tpfloors/?start=1496188800&end=1496275199&aggregation=day**

i can get something like this:

```
  {
    "id": 49,
    "results": [
      {
        "count": 3,
        "timestamp": 1496188800
      }
    ]
  },
```

Best regards.